# How to add Web part page in site pages in SharePoint 2010 publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-foundation

How to add Web part page in site pages in SharePoint 2010 publishing site?

- I have publishing feature enabled
- Do not want to create web part page in pages library

Answer (score 0):

Not sure do I understand the question. But I take you want to create web part page in 'Site Pages' intsead of the 'Pages' library. Then you simply navigate to the 'Site pages' [YoursiteURL]/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx and click on add new item. Web part page created from the UI needs to reside in some library. With VS studio you could create web part page deployed to the _layouts folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add publishing web part pages to Site pages library. But, you CAN create wiki pages there and add web parts to those wiki pages.

There is a very good discussion about the differences between Site pages and Pages libraries [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/the-diffence-between-pages-and-site-pages).