# Add new page in sharepoint

Tags: 2016

I can't find any option to add a new page in SharePoint 2016

[image]

Any thoughts ?!

Comment: what do u have for permission level?

Comment: the current user is system account!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the “Wiki Page Home Page” feature. The feature will create 
those libraries and will also create a wiki page and set it as the 
home (welcome) page for your site.

Activate **SharePoint Server Publishing** Feature for Add Page Option in Settings Menu.

A **Pages library** is a document library that contains all the content pages for a publishing site. A site that has thousands or tens of thousands of pages stored in the Pages library must consider a unique set of issues that relate to managing these pages, and providing navigation between them in a site.

**Site Pages** library that contains all your pages (including the home page) so as you create new content.

Reference:

[The diffence between Pages and Site Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/the-diffence-between-pages-and-site-pages)

Comment: thanks but the site pages not there,

Comment: Is it a publishing site or Team site or Collaboration Site?

Comment: yeeh, but I guess he want to be viwed on Settings Dropdown

Comment: Could u check if  you have Page Library created on your site?

Comment: it's project site

Comment: Activate the “Wiki Page Home Page” feature.

Comment: great it's worked , but still can't find add an page in gear menu

Comment: Activate **SharePoint Server Publishing** to achieve that.. Once problem solved don't forget to mark as answer to close the question

Comment: sure, let me try it