# Delete Site Pages and Pages Library from Site Content

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, sitepages

I am not using Site Pages and Pages Library in my Site. Can I delete them from Site Contents? Will that effect my Site negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it will create a major problem, since the url of your site defaults on the Home page (called home.aspx or default.aspx) included in Site Pages.

Comment: I have made my Document Library's AllItems.aspx page as default home page. What about now?

Comment: then technically you can remove it with no error messages. Still I believe pages (at least one) have their own use.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that deleting them will cause issues for your site.

The reason for this is that these page libraries are added by default when a Site is created so that SharePoint knows where to look for specific items, in this case pages.

*So what's the difference between "Site Pages" and "Pages"?* I hear you asking.
At the base level, one is used for "Wiki pages" and the other for Branding pages (as found [here](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-site-pages-vs-pages-library/)).

More details can be found on this question: [The diffence between Pages and Site Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/the-diffence-between-pages-and-site-pages)

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to do so, but it is possible , if you can't see "Delete this document library" option you can use power-shell as below to allow Deletion

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp/sites/xyz

$list = $web.Lists["Site Pages"]

$list.AllowDeletion = $True

$list.Update()


or you can delete it directly 


$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp/sites/xyz

$list = $web.Lists["Site Pages"]

$list.Delete()
```

deleted library and list will be moved to recycle bin and you can restore it later